# Populate selection field from loop odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How populate selection field from loop?

Example:

```
date = fields.Selection([],string='Date')

list = []

for i in diff:
    print(i)  #return 07:00


self.date = list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get selection field  key,value  pair via following method.

```
    result=self.env[model].fields_get([field_name])
    key=False
    if result and result.get(field_name) and result.get(field_name).get('selection'):
        for dict_value in result.get(field_name).get('selection'):
            print dict_value
```

This may help you.